# Error while running xperfasm JMH profiler on windows: xperf: error: NT Kernel Logger: Invalid flags. (0x3ec)

Tags: java, windows, profiling, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm adding microbenchmark to my JAVA application thanks to JMH.

I'm running the benchmarks on windows 10:

The **stack** profiler works well:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -prof stack
```

> Secondary result
>   "benchmark.ValueExtractorBench.cleanValue_Benchmark:·stack": Stack profiler:
>
> ....[Thread state distributions]....................................................................
>
> ```
> 99.7%         RUNNABLE
>  0.3%         WAITING
> ```
>
> ....[Thread state: RUNNABLE]........................................................................
>
> ```
>  26.6%  26.7% java.lang.String.regionMatches
>  23.2%  23.2% blabla...
> ```

But the **xperfasm** fails at init:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -prof xperfasm
```

> # Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:00
>   # Fork: 1 of 5
>   # Preparing profilers: WinPerfAsmProfiler Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start xperf: [xperf: error: NT Kernel Logger: Invalid flags. (0x3ec). ]
>
> ```
> at org.openjdk.jmh.profile.WinPerfAsmProfiler.beforeTrial(WinPerfAsmProfiler.java:129)
> at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.runSeparate(Runner.java:649)
> at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.runBenchmarks(Runner.java:561)
> at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:320)
> at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:209)
> at org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(Main.java:71)
> ```

**Note**: xperfasm is well listed in the available profilers (`-lprof`)

I'd like to be able to profile my microbenchmarks with more complete data than those given by the **stack** profiler.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yep, need to run as admin. Also, you will need the hsdis plugin to get assembly output.

Answer (score 0):

I observed exactly this exact error-code when i tried to run this from a console **without admin privileges**.